# How to access the data from multiple documents within a collection with self Join in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have stored the data in ArangoDB 2.7.1 as with collection name DSP:

```
{"content": "Book.xml", "type": "string", "name": "name", "key": 102}
{"content": "D:/XMLexample/Book.xml", "type": "string", "name": "location", "key": 102}
{"content": "xml", "type": "string", "name": "mime-type", "key": 102}
{"content": 4130, "type": "string", "name": "size", "key": 102}
{"content": "Sun Aug 25 07:53:32 2013", "type": "string", "name": "created_date", "key": 102}
{"content": "Wed Jan 23 09:14:07 2013", "type": "string", "name": "modified_date", "key": 102}
{"content": "catalog", "type": "tag", "name": "root", "key": 102}
{"content": "book", "type": "string", "name": "tag", "key": 103} 
{"content": "bk101", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "id", "key": 103}
{"content": "Gambardella, Matthew", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "author", "key": 1031} 
{"content": "XML Developer's Guide", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "title", "key": 1031}
{"content": "Computer", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "genre", "key": 1031}
{"content": "44.95", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "price", "key": 1031}
{"content": "2000-10-01", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "publish_date", "key": 1031}
{"content": "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "description", "key": 1031}
```

Here, a single set `{"content": "Book.xml", "type": "string", "name": "name", "key": 102}` represents a single document in collection.

Now, I want to access all the documents with the similar value of the `key` attribute in multiple documents or the value title and price where genre is computer" for the same `key` value.  I have tried an AQL as `FOR p IN DSP filter p.name == "publish_date" AND p.content == "2000-10-01" AND p.name == 'title' return p` but this is returning an empty set because it is comparing within the single document, Not in a collection.

Like relational database, there is some kind of self join will required but I don't know how the self join will applied. Please tell me how can I access the all documents with same value of the key attribute where `publish_date` is "2000-10-01". I expect the result of this query the following documents because corresponding to `publish_date` with value 2000-10-01 the value of `key` is 1031:

```
{"content": "Gambardella, Matthew", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "author", "key": 1031} 
{"content": "XML Developer's Guide", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "title", "key": 1031}
{"content": "Computer", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "genre", "key": 1031}
{"content": "44.95", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "price", "key": 1031}
{"content": "2000-10-01", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "publish_date", "key": 1031}
{"content": "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.", "type": {"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}, "name": "description", "key": 1031}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the publish date is stored in attribute `name` and its value in attribute `content`, you will first need to find all documents with that combination:

```
FOR self IN DSP 
  FILTER self.name == 'publish_date' && self.content == '2000-10-01'
  RETURN self
```

Now, with these documents being found, you can join them with the DSP collection again, filtering out documents that have the same `key` value, but excluding the already found documents from the initial `FOR`:

```
FOR self IN DSP 
  FILTER self.name == 'publish_date' && self.content == '2000-10-01'
  FOR other IN DSP 
    FILTER other.key == self.key && other._key != self._key 
    RETURN { self, other }
```

If you're always filtering on name and content and/or key, it may be sensible to index these attributes. It looks like `key` deserves an index on its own. A hash index should suffice as `key` will always be equality-compared. `name` and `content` (in this order) can be put into a skiplist index.